# How to control (enable/disable) Google Place Autocomplete fragment edit functionality

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am developing a carpooling app (from and to my university) on the Android platform. In my Google map, I have 2 place autocomplete fragments (called "From" and "To") and a *ride request* button. Once the app knows the user's current location, it should set one of the place autocomplete fragments to the university's location and disable any changing/editing on that fragment (i.e. if the user's location is at the university, it'll set the "From" autocomplete fragment to the university's location. Thus, disabling that fragment's functionality because I don't want the user to choose to get picked up from somewhere other than the university).

Likewise, if their location was NOT at the university, that means they need a ride TO the university. So, the second fragment, the "To" fragment should be fixed to the university's location. Hence, it should be disabled in order to prevent the user from requesting a ride to some place other than the university.

My question is: how can I disable/enable a Place Autocomplete Fragment?

I hope it is clear what I am trying to accomplish. I would highly appreciate any help or ideas of how I should approach this.

The following function is called from onConnected() as well as onLocationChanged():

```
private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
    Log.i(TAG, location.toString());

    //Place current location marker
    LatLng currentlatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    Location university = new Location("");
    university.setLatitude(-33.8688);
    university.setLongitude(151.2093);

    float distanceInMeters = location.distanceTo(university);
    /*
        NOTE: this is assuming the user is rider.
        Compute distance between current location and University,
        if distance is >= 1000m, then set destination ("To" fragment) to University.
        Otherwise (distance is < 1000m), set source location ("From" fragment) to University
     */
    if(distanceInMeters >= 1000.0) {
        toPlaceAutocomplete.setText("University");
    } else {
        fromPlaceAutocomplete.setText("University");
    }

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(currentlatLng);
    markerOptions.title("I am here!");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    //move map camera
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentlatLng));
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
}
```

Inside the if statement, when the fragment's text is set, I would like to disable  searching. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is getting the `AppCompatEditText` object contained within the `PlaceAutocompleteFragment` and call `AppCompatEditText.setEnabled(false)` to disable it.

```
  PlaceAutocompleteFragment originAutocomplete = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.originAutocomplete);
  AppCompatEditText originEditText = (AppCompatEditText) originAutocomplete.getView().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_input);
  originEditText.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
autocompleteFragment.getView().setEnabled(false);
```